# Method not found after spreading two objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object with two methods, this is a kind of base object and each methods can be overridden afterward.

```
 const base = {
        getStepsTitles: () => {
            return [
                "title 1",
                "title 2",
                "title 3"
            ];
        },
        setStepsTitles: (setters) => {
            const titles = this.getStepsTitles(); // this method here is overriden

            for (let [index, setter] of setters.entries())
                setter(titles[index]);
        }
    };
```

For instance, if I create a function like this

```
function NewMessages()
{
   this.getStepsTitles = () => {
            return [
                "new title 1",
                "new title 2",
                "new title 3"
            ];
        }
}
```

When I use the spread operator like this, the getStepsTitles called from the "base" object throws an error as if it was not existing. But my object clearly has it `{ getStepsTitles: ƒ, setStepsTitles: ƒ }`

```
const newMsg = new NewMessages();

var test = { 
...base,
...newMsg
}

test.setStepsTitles([ 
   (t)=>{console.log(t)},
   (t)=>{console.log(t)},
   (t)=>{console.log(t)}
]);
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

```js
const base = {
  getStepsTitles: () => {
    return [
      "title 1",
      "title 2",
      "title 3"
    ];
  },
  setStepsTitles: (setters) => {
    const titles = this.getStepsTitles(); // this method here is overriden

    for (let [index, setter] of setters.entries())
      setter(titles[index]);
  }
};

function NewMessages() {
  this.getStepsTitles = () => {
    return [
      "new title 1",
      "new title 2",
      "new title 3"
    ];
  }
}

const newMsg = new NewMessages();

var test = {
  ...base,
  ...newMsg
}

test.setStepsTitles([
  (t) => {
    console.log(t)
  },
  (t) => {
    console.log(t)
  },
  (t) => {
    console.log(t)
  }
]);
```

Comment: The syntax for `NewMessages` is incorrect; it should be either `getStepsTitles: () => {` or `this.getStepsTitles = () => {`.

Comment: I did not paste the exact code from my source, but it does not fix the problem

Comment: I don't think `this` is what you think it is in `setStepsTitles`; you may want to `console.dir(this)` before using it...

Comment: It seems to work in the code snippet if I replace the arrow functions, but I can't manage to make it work in my source, I probably have something else, thx